# May I use "parted with his life" for "died"?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, collocations

Can the phrase *to part with one's life* be used figuratively as a synonym to the verb *to die*?

> John didn't care about his health and parted with his life in his
>   early 30's.

Comment: I can't recall ever seeing this.  It was more "left this world".

Comment: No. You might also try: "John didn't care about his health and called it a day in his early 30's.

Comment: Or, "...*and **checked out** in his early 30's*".  Plenty of euphemisms for death/dying...

Answer (score 1):

It's not a commonly known/heard phrase (at least in American Midwest English). That doesn't mean that it wouldn't be understood, though. It has kind of a poetic feel to it, so if that's what you're going for it works.

If you're looking for something more commonplace and somber, "passed away" is a commonly used and understood way of saying "died." Some phrases are more somber/serious than others so it depends on the tone you're trying to convey.

Comment: Yes, I mean a metaphor or even something ironic.